# Multiple callback functions with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, callback

```
function one(x){
    return x+1;
}
function two(y){
    return y+2;
}
function three(z){
    return y+3;
}
function four(k){
    return k/4;
}

function start(...array){
    
    //passing all functions in order with each element of array and prints 
    //for example
    //prints (10+1+2+3)/4 
    //prints (11+1+2+3)/4 
    //prints (12+1+2+3)/4
    //
}

start(10,11,12);
```

The first solution that came to my mind in this question was to use rest parameters and callback. Is this the best way? Rest parameters passing n time arguments and callback can call functions in an order. However, i couldn't find a way to use callback functions in such problem.

Is there a way to use callback functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take all functions in an array and reduce the values.

The function collects all parameters in an array.

This array of values is mapped by using a reduce method for all wanted functions and each value is taken as start value for reducing.

Finally the collected values are printed to the console.

```js
function one(x) { return x + 1; }
function two(y) { return y + 2; }
function three(z) { return z + 3; }
function four(k) { return k / 4; }

function start(...array) {
    array
        .map(x => [one, two, three, four].reduce((x, fn) => fn(x), x))
        .forEach(x => console.log(x));
}

start(10, 11, 12);
```

Comment: at first, thank you! I have a question. I have 3 parameters (10,11,12) and 4 functions (one, two, three, four). How foreach works? According to function number or parameter number? I couldnt understand the reduce and foreach part of your code. Can you explain  how start function is working?

Comment: @Zagano, please see edit. (and have a look to [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the solution like this:

```js
function one(x){
    return x+1;
}
function two(y){
    return y+2;
}
function three(z){
    return z+3;
}
function four(k){
    return k/4;
}

function start(...array){
    for (var item of array) {
      //           10      10+1        10+2         10+3         10/4
      //           11      11+1        11+2         11+3         11/4
      //           12      12+1        12+2         12+3         12/4
      console.log(item + one(item) + two(item) + three(item) + four(item));
    }
}

start(10,11,12);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the functions in order for each of the elements in the array.

```js
function one(x){
    return x+1;
}
function two(y){
    return y+2;
}
function three(z){
    return z+3;
}
function four(k){
    return k/4;
}

function start(...array){
  for(let num of array){
    console.log(four(three(two(one(num)))));
  } 
    //passing all functions in order with each element of array and prints 
    //for example
    //prints (10+1+2+3)/4 
    //prints (11+1+2+3)/4 
    //prints (12+1+2+3)/4
    //
}

start(10,11,12);
```